# In iOS, is there any standard mechanism for color pickers?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, color-picker

I'm at a loss trying to find anything relevant to this question. Basically, I'm looking to write an app that's kind of like a color picker / swatch library (but with a certain purpose in mind) and I'd like to be able to use it in virtually any app that deals with color selection. Is there any built in, or perhaps novel way, I could either modify some config variable, or send some kind of signal that updates the current color? Or I guess the real question would be, is there any concept of a global color in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referring to `tintColor`?

From Apple [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html):

> Using Tint Color
>
> In iOS 7, tint color is a property of UIView. iOS 7 apps often use a
>   tint to define a key color that indicates interactivity and selection
>   state for UI elements throughout the app.
>
> When you specify a tint for a view, the tint is automatically
>   propagated to all subviews in the view’s hierarchy. Because UIWindow
>   inherits from UIView, you can specify a tint color for the entire app
>   by setting the window’s tint property using code like this:
>
> window.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

From Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tintColor):

> The first nondefault tint color value in the view’s hierarchy,
>   ascending from and starting with the view itself.

I hope that helps.